# Defining dynamic Database Configuration using JPA

Tags: jpa

As per the JPA specification a persistence.xml is mandated which has the persistence unit name , transaction type JTA ( Since I will be using it in a Java EE container ) datasource name , user id and password.

The above holds good for either container managed entity manager  injected using @PersistenceContext or Application managed entity manager factory  injected using @PersistenceUnit.

My query is in case of single Instance of server serving multiple database I have different datasources depending upon the region the application would be serving hence I want to be able to define the datasource at runtime rather than during compilation time using persistence.xml.

I have tried using Persistence API to create an entity manager factory but this method seems to be not required for any container to provide support.

Though I would like to follow the jee specification when defining the persistence layer, this specific item of being able to address multiple datasources at runtime does not looks like an out of box feature provided by JPA.

Incase of Hibernate direct implementation I have the ability to programmatically set the required datasource. Has anyone come across a similar situation and choose to go with Hibernate or any persistence provider implementation rather than hardcoding the specifics to a build specific persistence.xml ?

Comment: What application server are you using? Must your application be portable to other application server products?

Comment: Hi Simon I am using Websphere and would require my application to be portable for future.

Comment: I think that is "only" possible with multiple persistence units, with the same configuration but different datasource. With CDI you can make them available via producer methods whereby the EntityManagers are produced for different qualifiers. You could retrieve them via **Instance<EntityManager> emInstances** and select them by their qualifier, whereby the qualifier is provided by another bean, which is aware of the current region. Not quite what you asked, but worth looking at: https://antoniogoncalves.org/2014/05/25/switch-datasource-with-cdi-alternatives-and-stereotypes/